# How to get diff between all files inside 2 folders that are on the web?

Tags: linux, svn, git, file, diff

So I want to [compare this folder](http://cloudobserver.googlecode.com/svn/branches/v0.4/Boost.Extension.Tutorial/libs/boost/extension/) `http://cloudobserver.googlecode.com/svn/branches/v0.4/Boost.Extension.Tutorial/libs/boost/extension/` with [this](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost/extension/) `http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost/extension/`. I want to get a diff file as a result. These folders are under svn control but I'd prefer git styled diff file (like one [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836948/boost-extension-simple-inheritance-sample-why-we-see-no-animals-on-linux/5838527#5838527)) I tried `git diff` but it seems not to work that way for web folders. So how to do the same thing with one command on Linux?

***Update:***
So we had [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874090/linux-how-to-get-diff-between-all-files-inside-2-folders-that-are-on-the-web/5874256#5874256). But it works strangely - it seems to me it shows that all files (same files) have all theire contents replaced with very same contents (while I know for sure that there were only like 3-4 code lines changed at all)...

***Update 2:***
To achieve what I really needed (dif file with only really changed lines, with git styling, on Linux) do:

```
$ svn export http://cloudobserver.googlecode.com/svn/branches/v0.4/Boost.Extension.Tutorial/libs/boost/extension/ repos2 --native-eol CRLF
$ svn export http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost/extension/ repos --native-eol CRLF
$ git diff repos repos2 > fileWithReadableDiff.diff
```

Comment: haha; I just noticed you linked to my diff with [`one shown here`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836948/boost-extension-simple-inheritance-sample-why-we-see-no-animals-on-linux/5838527#5838527)... wotta coincidence

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Once you have the source trees, e.g.

```
diff -ENwbur repos1/ repos2/
```

Even better

```
diff -ENwbur repos1/ repos2/  | kompare -o -
```

and have a crack at it in a good gui tool :)

- -Ewb ignore the bulk of whitespace changes
- -N detect new files
- -u unified
- -r recurse

Comment: so... yep - loved your [`diff style`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836948/boost-extension-simple-inheritance-sample-why-we-see-no-animals-on-linux/5838527#5838527), sent a full diff patch on yours+mine boost.extension to Jeremy... (see this post update for my way of getting it)... I still wonder how to do such thing with one line=)

Comment: Well thanks for the accept; I guess my [original (rev. 2) instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5849377/revisions#spacer-4f409b65-3284-40a8-99db-770fdbc477be) in that other post hid my secret: I used 'git svn clone ... http://svn..../branches/v0.4' and just edited locally. It then becomes a simple `git diff` or git `format-patch` depending on how much work was done

Comment: didn't know about kompare before, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: would be nice to add a reference to `kompare` as it's an external package (at least on my Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: You can totally use notepad++ with Language set on "Diff" it works like a charm (without kompare)

Comment: @Hybris95 does that do side-by-side diffs? Personally, I don't take to context/unified diffs too well

Answer (score 3):

You urls are not in the same repository, so you can't do it with the `svn diff` command.

```
svn: 'http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost/extension' isn't in the same repository as 'http://cloudobserver.googlecode.com/svn'
```

Another way you could do it, is export each repos using `svn export`, and then use the diff command to compare the 2 directories you exported.

```
// Export repositories
svn export http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost/extension/ repos1
svn export http://cloudobserver.googlecode.com/svn/branches/v0.4/Boost.Extension.Tutorial/libs/boost/extension/ repos2

// Compare exported directories
diff repos1 repos2 > file.diff
```

Comment: I replaced last line with `git diff repos1 repos2 > file2.diff` and it got more informative... but it seems to me it shows that all files (same files) have all thare contents replaced with wary same contents (while I know for sure that there were only like 3 code lines changed at all)...