# How to do a "diff" of an entire directory tree? Is there a software available?

Tags: svn, diff

Assume  there are 2 directory trees

```
D:\dir1\
```

and

```
C:\dir2
```

Now I want to create a diff report between the directories and files, So not only I need a report which says which files have been modified and what has been modified between the main directories but also the report must give me details of any files or sub directories that have been deleted or added new etc

Should I checkin the dir1 to subversion and then do a check with dir2 ? If so how should I proceed?

Or is there an easier way to proceed? Any directory diff software available?

This can be both Windows based or Linux based.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874090/how-to-get-diff-between-all-files-inside-2-folders-that-are-on-the-web

Answer (score 21):

In Linux `diff -r directory1 directory2` would give you that information.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using Windows, you can check out WinMerge which does diffs of folders: http://winmerge.org/

Comment: Same functionality exists in AraxisMerge too.

Answer (score 2):

"BeyondCompare" (from Scooter Software) has a very nice graphical interface for comparing directory trees (and the files themselves as well).  It is available for Windows, Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

**KDiff3** is an open source file and directory diff and merge tool.
Runs under Linux, Windows & MacOSX

http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

The various [Jetbrains IDE's](https://www.jetbrains.com/products.html) all have an awesome [Compare Directories](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/comparing-folders.html) feature. They have free trials, and some of the IDE's even have free versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try [pkgdiff](http://lvc.github.io/pkgdiff/) to visualize differences between directories (added/removed/renamed/moved files and changed content):

```
pkgdiff -d DIR-0/ DIR-1/
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Devart has a good product called [Code Compare](https://www.devart.com/codecompare/) that will do both a file diff and a directory diff. It also has a Windows Explorer Context Menu addin.

There is a free and paid version of the application

Answer (score 0):

This free diff software will do it: [Source Gear Diff Merge](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge) I am not affiliated with the source gear company.