# About the armlink behavior when the linked object is not explicitly used by the main executable

Tags: dll, linker, arm

I want to link the example with liba.so, even though the example is NOT using anything inside the liba.so:

```
    armlink --userlibpath /mylib/lib liba.so --fpic --shared 
        -o example main.o demo.o
```

I get nothing from `readelf -d example | grep NEEDED`, it seems that armlink does some optimization to remove the linked library which is referenced by the "example".

If I want the liba.so be *always* linked into example, what need I do with armlink options?

Any information is very appreciated ;)

Comment: Here's how you'd do it with gcc, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767925/how-to-force-gcc-to-link-unreferenced-static-c-objects-from-a-libraray I am not familiar with armlink but it looks different, but this might give you ideas for the kinds of option to look for.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for similar "-Wl,--whole-archive -lyourlib" in armlink... but no progress so far, does any expert on armlink give some help ? many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

7 years ago, well, anyway.
You need *--keep* armlink option

> *--keep*
>   This option specifies input sections that must not be removed by unused section elimination.

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0804b/CHDJGJEC.html