# C/cmake - how to add a linker flag to an (unused) library when the library is specified in TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES?

Tags: c, linker, cmake

In the root directory of my project, I have a subdirectory for `my_lib` and another for `my_app`.
The library `my_lib` defines tables that populates a section defined by the linker, these tables are not used directly by `my_app`, so this library is not linked.

To force my_lib to be linked I added the flag --whole-archive as described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116420/how-to-force-gcc-to-link-an-unused-static-library)

And it works!

In the CMakelist.txt of the root directory I have the following:

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-mmcu=cc430f6137 -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--whole-archive -lMY_LIB -Wl,--no-whole-archive")
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(my_lib)
```

In the `CMakelist.txt` of `my_lib` I have:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(MY_LIB
    my_lib.c
)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MY_LIB)
```

In the `CMakelist.txt` of `my_app` I have:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(my_app my_app.c)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(my_app MY_LIB)
```

My problem is I just want to use this flag (`--whole-archive`) if `MY_LIB` is specified in the `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` in `CMakelist.txt` of `my_app`.

If the the last line `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(my_app MY_LIB)` is not there, I don't want to add `"-Wl,--whole-archive -lMY_LIB -Wl,--no-whole-archive"` in the `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`.

I tried to remove this flag from the CMakelist.txt in root and add the following into the `CMakelist.txt` in `my_lib` subdirectory:

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(MY_LIB PROPERTIES CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--whole-archive -lMY_LIB -Wl,--no-whole-archive")
```

But this does not work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The CMake command [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) allows for specifying both libraries and flags when linking a given target. Instead of directly using the target name `MY_LIB` in the `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` call, use a variable that wraps the reference to `MY_LIB` with the `--whole-archive` and `--no-whole-archive` flags:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(MY_LIB
    my_lib.c
)
SET(MY_LIB_LINK_LIBRARIES -Wl,--whole-archive MY_LIB -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
...
ADD_EXECUTABLE(my_app my_app.c)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(my_app ${MY_LIB_LINK_LIBRARIES})
```