# Android NDK CMake linking issues

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, linker, cmake

I'm quite new with NDK + Gradle + CMake integration and I'm trying to understand why linking doesn't export symbols as intended.

I have a static library built by a `CMakeLists.txt` which is not the main `CMakeLists.txt`.

The scripts does something like:

```
# main CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(${LIBS}/foo libs}

add_library(native SHARED native.cpp)
# omitting standard android libraries
target_link_libraries(native foo ${android-lib} ${log-lib})
```

while `CMakeLists.txt` inside `${libs}/foo` is the following:

```
# misc configuration of ${SRC}
add_library(foo STATIC ${SRC})
```

The script works fine, it's able to link `libnative.so` and I'm able to find the generated `libfoo.a`. Everything seems fine.

I then try to define a native method in `foo.cpp` contained in foo library:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_mypackage_Controls_onTap(JNIEnv*, jobject, int x, int y) {
  // log something
}
```

But I'm not able to call the native method defined in foo library. I get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` at runtime. If, instead, I move (directly by copying and pasting) the method to native.cpp then everything goes fine.

So basically:

- **Java -> method in native.cpp** works
- **Java -> method in native.cpp -> method defined in foo library** works
- **Java -> method in foo library** doesn't work (`UnsatisfiedLinkError`)

I tried to inspect the exported functions with `nm` and it looks like that `foo.a` correctly exports the native function as I can see

```
00011060 T Java_com_mypackage_Controls_onTap
```

But this entry disappears from `libnative.so`. If, instead, I define the method directly in native.cpp then I can see it correctly with nm also on `libnative.so`.

In addition calling any method in `foo` library from `native.cpp` works as intended so the library is effectively statically linked.

I am not able to understand the reason behind this, the approach should be fine, visibility should be correct as specified by `JNIEXPORT` macro so I'm really groping in the dark (and Gradle doesn't provide any output of compilation phase so I can't understand what's happening, but the build.ninja file seems correct)

Comment: Have you tried to add `set( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on )`? From your explanation it is hard to tell what went wrong - either the symbol is stripped from libnative.so, or that linking libfoo.a is skipped altogether.

Comment: @AlexCohn linking of libfoo.a is not skipped as I'm able to invoke a method of libfoo from libnative and it correctly links and works. It seems like the symbol is stripped or not exported visibly from outside but I tried to force -fvisibility=default without any success. Unfortunately the generator used is not make so there is no makefile. I can see the invocation command and it seems correct. The so is generated by liking native.o and libfoo.a. I've really no clues..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior, even if unpleasant, is correct. The linker drops any object "files" (in your case, **foo.o**) from used static libraries, unless they are "pinned" by one of the objects in the shared lib (in your case, **native.o**). There are three ways to solve the problem:

1. compile **foo.cpp** as part of **libnative.so** instead of a
   static lib.
2. reference `Java_com_mypackage_Controls_onTap` or any other
   external symbol from `foo.cpp` in `native.cpp`
3. use `SET(native -Wl,--whole-archive foo -Wl,--no-whole-archive)` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17477559/192373)

Comment: Thanks, by keeping with searches to related issued (not involving Android NDK) I reached the same conclusion. While using `--whole-archive` seems like the panacea to solve this issue, I was wondering if there's a way to mark specific methods as "export always", maybe through an `__attribute__` just to keep things sane, not just by blindly exporting any symbol of any object file (since in the end just maybe 10 out of 1000 will be used)?

Comment: No, there exists no linker option "keep symbols a, b and q even if nobody needs them". But (see *2.* above) it's easy to simulate such option. If you switch from implicit JNI binding to explicit **RegisterNatives()**, you will get this automatically.