# CMake target_link_libraries not linking shared library

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

I have the following app being built and linked using CMake.

```
add_executable(my_node main.cpp)    
target_link_libraries(my_node dynamic_lib my_dependency)
```

The source of `my_node` DOES NOT use `dynamic_lib` directly. `my_dependency` requires `dynamic_lib` to run.

Using readelf and ldd, I can see that `dynamic_lib` is not found on `my_node`; my app fails to launch. I can launch the app by instead setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/dynamic_lib_dir" bash -c './my_node'
```

Alternatively, if I use classes from `dynamic_lib` in `my_node` source, it all works. I think I'm missing some CMake configuration here to force `my_node` to directly link with `dynamic_lib`. How can I bundle all of this up neatly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C/cmake - how to add a linker flag to an (unused) library when the library is specified in TARGET\_LINK\_LIBRARIES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470350/c-cmake-how-to-add-a-linker-flag-to-an-unused-library-when-the-library-is-sp)

Comment: I do not believe so. I have tried in Cmake and directly with c++. The resulting binary cannot resolve my lib.

`/usr/bin/c++ ... -Wl,--whole-archive /path/to/dynamic_lib.so -Wl,--no-whole-archive \ `

ldd still declares `dynamic_lib.so => not found`

Comment: Since only `my_dependency` directly needs `dynamic_lib`, why not link `dynamic_lib` to `my_dependency` instead?

Comment: @Chris: if `ldd` says that dynamic_lib is not found, then it is linked to your executable, but then at runtime it can't be resolved unless you use the environment variable $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. This is what solves RPATH. See https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling

Comment: The title is misleading: the library is actually **linked** into your executable. As result, `ldd` shows entry for the library. The reason, why corresponded library file is not found, is RPATH settings. See there for more details: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling