# How do I get GNU __attribute__((constructor)) to work in a library?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, gnu, autotools

I can get GNU `__attribute__((constructor))` to work (for a C++ program) if I link all object files together in a single link, but it doesn't work anymore if I store the object file containing the constructor function in a library and then link the library rather than the object file.  What am I doing wrong?

Makefile.am:

```
SUBDIRS = src
```

src/Makefile.am:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello
hello_SOURCES = hello.cc register.cc register.hh myfunc.cc
```

src/hello.cc:

```
#include <iostream>             // for cout
#include <map>

#include "register.hh"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Have " << functions.size() << " functions registered."
    << std::endl;
  for (Function_map::iterator it = functions.begin(); it != functions.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << "Registered " << (*it).first << std::endl;
    (*it).second();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

src/register.cc:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

#include "register.hh"

Function_map functions;

void register_function(const std::string& name, Function f)
{
  functions[name] = f;
}
```

src/register.hh:

```
#ifndef REGISTER_H_
#define REGISTER_H_

#include <map>
#include <string>

typedef void (*Function)();

typedef std::map<const std::string, Function> Function_map;
extern Function_map functions;

void register_function(const std::string& name, Function f);

#endif
```

src/myfunc.cc:

```
#include "register.hh"

#include <iostream>

void myfunc()
{
  std::cout << "This is myfunc!" << std::endl;
}

__attribute__((constructor))
void register_myfunc()
{
  register_function("MYFUNC", myfunc);
}
```

configure.ac:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([hello], [1.4], [bugs@my.domain])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/hello.cc])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([auxiliary])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror])

AC_PROG_CXX
AM_PROG_AR

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile
                 src/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

so all C++ files are compiled into object files which get linked together into the 'hello' executable.

The output from the resulting 'hello' program is:

```
Hello, World!
Have 1 functions registered.
Registered MYFUNC
This is myfunc!
```

If I change src/Makefile.am to

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello
hello_SOURCES = hello.cc register.cc register.hh
hello_LDADD = liblibrary.a

noinst_LIBRARIES = liblibrary.a
liblibrary_a_SOURCES = myfunc.cc
```

(i.e., myfunc.cc compiles into myfunc.o which is stored in liblibrary.a which gets linked with the other object files into 'hello'), then the output from 'hello' is

```
Hello, World!
Have 0 functions registered.
```

so now the 'register_myfunc' function wasn't executed.  Why not?

**EDITED 2015-02-22** (in response to the answer from Basile Starynkevitch): I'm using a GNU/Linux (Fedora 20) system.  I tried building a shared library using libtools, but without success.  I adjusted the src/Makefile.am as follows:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello
hello_SOURCES = hello.cc register.cc register.hh
hello_LDADD = liblibrary.la

noinst_LTLIBRARIES = liblibrary.la
liblibrary_la_SOURCES = myfunc.cc
liblibrary_la_LDFLAGS = -shared -fPIC
```

(first with just `-shared`, later with `-fPIC` too) and added `LT_INIT` to configure.ac, but that did not change the outcome.  I'll try the "static data with explicit constructor" trick that you mention for C++, but am still interested to know how to get my example to work with `__attribute__((constructor))`.

**EDITED 2015-02-23** I tried the "static data with explicit constructor" trick but got the same results as before: it works if all objects files are linked together explicitly into an executable, but not if the thing that I want constructed automatically is linked into the executable through a library.

Adding `hello_LDFLAGS = -Wl,--whole-archive` (suggested by David Grayson) leads to many "multiple definition" errors.  Automake places those flags near the beginning of the link command so it applies not just to the library.  Automake recommends against including linker flags directly in `hello_LDADD` where the library to link with is specified.  It is possible to override Automake rules with explicit Make rules (where I can put the linker flags exactly where I want them), but then I may run the risk of other standard Make rules (supplied by Automake) misbehaving.

I'll see if I can get it to work using `dlopen`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have a Linux system. then ensure that the library is built as a shared library (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28067471/841108)), not a static one.

Functions with `__attribute__(constructor)` will be called when that shared library is loaded, e.g. at `ld.so` time, or at `dlopen` time if the library is a loaded plugin.

BTW the  `__attribute__(constructor)` is more useful in C than in C++. In C++ you don't really need it, since you could have  `static` data with some *explicitly defined* constructor in its `class` to achieve the same result.

For details, read [Drepper's paper: *How to Write a Shared Library*](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf).

Comment: Just a note: One time I tried to use a C++ shared library in C & Pascal programs.. and because I used static instead of explicitly instantiating it, I got a bunch of crashes and weird behaviour. Not saying that this will happen, but it can ={  Specifically for iostreams and strings.. Got some _IosBase problem.

Comment: Tried your constructor trick, but got same behavior as before.  See edited post.  I'll try dlopen next.

Comment: I think the basic idea in linux is that shared library is treated as an executable while library archive is just that: a collection of object files. So a library archive is thought to be a place from which you explicitly pick what you want to include. While a shared library behaves like an executable without main. So a shared library can be cleaned up from any symbols that are not referenced by its exported symbols. While archive will have everything. This is why I think you have to specify explicitly with .a files what you want included. Even constructors.

Answer (score 3):

By default, GCC's linker will only link in your static library (`liblibrary.a`) if your program actually references some symbol from it.

### Just using the library

So one way to make your library get linked in would be to use a symbol from it.  For example, you could add this to `main.cc`:

```
void myfunc();
...
std::cout << (void *)&myfunc << std::endl;
```

Or you could just manually call some initialization function in the library.  At the point where you doing that, there is probably no reason to use `__attr__((constructor))` any more.

### Adding a linker option

Alternatively, you might try using the `-Wl,--whole-archive` option to the linker as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116420/how-to-force-gcc-to-link-an-unused-static-library).  To do that, you would add this line to src/Makefile.am:

```
hello_LDFLAGS = -Wl,--whole-archive
```

However, that caused my version of GCC to output tons of multiple definition errors for various symbols in `libgcc.a`, so I don't know if that is a real solution.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to explicitly reference the new object's code in my main program, but perhaps I can't.  The linker option for me leads to the linker errors that you mentioned.  Automake does not seem designed to solve my problem.  See edited post.

Comment: you need to also use -Wl,--no-whole-archive after you have defined your libraries. However I still haven't figured out how to make --gc-sections work correctly when using whole-archive...

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using -u link option and include driver init code from archives for drivers that I actually need. It seems reasonable since it's also a nice way to build everything and then control exactly what goes in the final program. I like this way a lot because I no longer need to supervise the compilation step with what gets included. I can compile and archive everything.

so when you link:

```
gcc -Wl,-u,myconstructor1,-u,myconstructor2 -o prog ... -llib1 -llib2
```

The generation of the list of constructors that you need can be automated based on selected features of the application. Although I have yet to figure out how to automate this using autotools.