# Order of static destructors

Tags: c++

If a class `Foo` has a static member variable `Bar`, I would expect `Bar`'s destructor to run only after the last instance of `Foo`'s destructor runs. This doesn't happen with the code snippet below (gcc 6.3, clang 3.8):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Foo;
static std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo;

struct Bar {
    Bar() {
        std::cout << "Bar()" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Bar() {
        std::cout << "~Bar()" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Foo {
    Foo() {
        std::cout << "Foo()" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "~Foo()" << std::endl;
    }

    static Bar bar;
};
Bar Foo::bar;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    foo = std::make_unique<Foo>();
}
```

Outputs:

```
Bar()
Foo()
~Bar()
~Foo()
```

Why is the order of destruction not the reverse of construction here?
If `~Foo()` uses `Foo::bar` this is a use after delete.

Comment: Have you tried to make the `~Foo()` use the `bar` data?

Comment: Yes, that's what led me to asking the question. It doesn't change the behavior, and leads to using a destroyed object.

Comment: There's no mechanism in the language which would ensure that something happens after all class instances are destroyed. A class doesn't maintain a counter of its instances or anything similar.

Comment: @n.m. No, but the compiler knows to construct `Foo::bar` before `Foo()` is run (allowing safe usage of `Foo::bar` in `Foo()` - one would hope this behavior would also apply to `~Foo()`.

Comment: The compiler knows only about static objects, and their destruction order has nothing to do with their types.

Comment: Well, I misunderstood a lot. [Static members __aren't__ guaranteed to be constructed before its first use](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff3fa11f42255349). @rthur No, it is simply the order in which you wrote them. Static members looks broken as hell though.

Comment: @PasserBy That's scary.. Replacing the static member with a [function with a static variable seems to work well enough though](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f24bba0bec849fe8)

Comment: Even though they both have `static`, they are different things.

Comment: Yes, but the end result is pretty much the same - a single instance per class.

Answer (score 11):

In C++ the objects are constructed in order of occurrence and destructed in the reverse order. First comes `foo` construction, then `bar` construction then `main` is executed then `bar` is destructed and then `foo`. This is the behavior you are seeing. The switch appears because the constructor of `foo` doesn't construct a `Foo`, it constructs an empty `unique_ptr`, so you don't get to see `Foo()` in the output. Then `bar` is constructed with the output and in `main` you create the actual `Foo` after `foo` has long been constructed.

Comment: Yes - using a `unique_ptr` is to mimic the behavior I have in a more complicated application. Is it therefore unsafe to use a static class member from a destructor (ie using `Foo::bar` in `~Bar()`? That sounds crazy.

Comment: @rthur One fix is to use `static std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo = std::make_unique<Foo>();` in the global `foo` declaration. Another is to write `foo = nullptr;` at the end of `main`. If that doesn't help please explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code snippet is a small example - in my application `Foo()` requires parameters from `argv`, and also need to be passed signals, hence being a global.

Comment: Are you sure that the *standard* mandates some particular order, notably with several translation units?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Different translation units don't have an order, so this doesn't apply. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2204628/3484570) has appropriate quotes from the standard.

Answer (score 3):

> I would expect Bar's destructor to run only after the last instance of Foo's destructor runs.

No, as a `static` data member, `Foo::bar` is independent of any instances of `Foo`.

And for the code you showed,

```
static std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo; // no Foo created here

Bar Foo::bar; // Foo::bar is initialized before main(), => "Bar()"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    foo = std::make_unique<Foo>(); // an instance of Foo is created, => "Foo()"
} 

// objects are destroyed in the reverse order how they're declared
// Foo::bar is defined after foo, so it's destroyed at first => "~Bar()"
// foo is destroyed; the instance of Foo managed by it is destroyed too => "~Foo()"
```

Comment: So, globals are destroyed before `main()` actually exits? Doesn't it look strange? What if `Foo` instance uses the `static Bar bar` data?

Comment: @Alex They're destroyed after `main()` ?

Comment: Let me be more clear: `~Foo()` theoretically may use `static Bar bar`.

Comment: @Alex Exactly - that's what led me to asking this question.

Comment: @Alex Then you'll get a destroyed object. Don't use global objects is a good idea; or move the definition of `Foo::bar` to the front.

Comment: Actually I missed the static pointer, so yes, using the globals that are dependent on each other is generally not good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The complication here is that the code doesn’t instrument the constructor of `foo`. What happens is that `foo` gets constructed first, than `Foo::bar` gets constructed. The call to `make…unique` constructs a `Foo` object. Then `main` exits, and the two static objects get destroyed in reverse order of their construction: `Foo::bar` gets destroyed, then `foo`. The destructor for `foo` destroys the `Foo` object that it points to, which is the one created in`main`.

Comment: `foo` doesn't seem to get constructed first though - `Foo::bar` is according to the output.

Comment: @rthur — the constructor for `foo` doesn’t write any output. After its construction it holds a null pointer.

Comment: I might be missing something - `Foo()` prints out `Foo()`.
Even so, would using `Foo::bar` in `Foo()` therefore be undefined behavior?

Comment: @rthur — the type of `foo` is `std::unique_ptr<Foo>`. Its default constructor does not create a `Foo` object. It holds a null pointer.

Comment: Ah yes sorry - I thought we were talking about when the `Foo` object is constructed, not the `foo` pointer. That explains the order of construction / destruction - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Static objects' lifetimes are based solely on the order of their definition. The compiler doesn't "know enough" when to call `Bar::Bar()` as much as calling `Bar::~Bar()`.

To illustrate the problem better, consider this

```
class Foo;

struct Bar {
    Bar() {
        std::cout << "Bar()" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Bar() {
        std::cout << "~Bar()" << std::endl;
    }

    void baz() {}
};

struct Foo {
    Foo() {
        bar.baz();
        std::cout << "Foo()" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "~Foo()" << std::endl;
    }

    static Bar bar;
};

Foo foo;
Bar Foo::bar;

int main() {}
```

Prints

```
Foo()
Bar()
~Bar()
~Foo()
```

The addition of `std::unique_ptr` postpones `Foo::Foo()` after its construction in main, giving the illusion of the compiler "knowing" when to call `Bar::Bar()`.

TLDR Static objects should be defined later than its dependencies. Before defining `bar`, it is just as much a bug to define a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` and to define a `Foo`

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not write code which depends on the order of construction or destruction of static (or global) data. This makes unreadable and unmaintainable code (you might prefer static smart pointers, or 
*explicit* initialization or startup routines called from `main`). And AFAIK that order is not specified when you link several translation units.

Notice that [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) provides the [`init_priority`](http://ttps://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html) and [`constructor`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) (with priority) attributes. I believe you should rather avoid using them. However, the `__attribute__(constructor)` [is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28652346/841108) useful [inside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26672678/841108) plugins, for plugin initialization.

In some cases, you might also use [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) (at least on POSIX systems). I don't know if such registered functions are called before or after destructors (and I think you should not care about that order).