# GDB Debugger - "malloc" not defined. Trying to assign C array with debugger

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, embedded, gnu

I've got some software compiled to run on an embedded NRF24 target, using a gcc-arm-none-eabi toolchain from [here](https://github.com/xpack-dev-tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc-xpack/releases/tag/v10.3.1-2.3) (a custom one that provides gdb with support for python3) . I'm trying essentially, `malloc` an array from the GDB debugger console at runtime, then fill it with elements that I provide.

I have a pointer defined in a .c file like: `static float32_t *array;`.
I want to then call a cmd like: `call (void*) malloc(num_of_elements*sizeof(float32_t))` from inside the GDB console to allocate an array at runtime, and then fill it with elements with something like maybe: `call (void*) memcpy(array, {var1, var2... var n}, n)`

My issue is the GDB debugger cannot find the `malloc` stdlib function. If I do something like:

```
break malloc 
Function "malloc" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) [answered N; input not from terminal]
```

It can't find this function, although it is fine with finding <string.h> fns, like `memcpy` for example and I can't quite work out why this is.

I have a feeling it could be something to do with linking, the program is built with a Makefile, the flags towards the end may be of interest:

```
LIB_FILES += \
  $(SDK_ROOT)/components/toolchain/cmsis/dsp/GCC/libarm_cortexM4lf_math.a \

# Optimization flags
OPT = -O0 -g3
# Uncomment the line below to enable link time optimization
#OPT += -flto

# C flags common to all targets
CFLAGS += $(OPT)
CFLAGS += -DBOARD_PCA10056
CFLAGS += -DARM_MATH_CM4
CFLAGS += -DBSP_DEFINES_ONLY
CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_GPIO_AS_PINRESET
CFLAGS += -DFLOAT_ABI_HARD
CFLAGS += -DNRF52840_XXAA
CFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m4
CFLAGS += -mthumb -mabi=aapcs
CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
# keep every function in a separate section, this allows linker to discard unused ones
CFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-strict-aliasing
CFLAGS += -fno-builtin -fshort-enums

CFLAGS += -DDEV8_PINOUT
CFLAGS += -DNUM_FLASH_BLOCKS=128
CFLAGS += -DDEBUG
CFLAGS += -DNRF_LOG_ENABLED=1
CFLAGS += -DNRF_LOG_BACKEND_UART_ENABLED=1

# C++ flags common to all targets
CXXFLAGS += $(OPT)
# Assembler flags common to all targets
ASMFLAGS += $(OPT)
ASMFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m4
ASMFLAGS += -mthumb -mabi=aapcs
ASMFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
ASMFLAGS += -DBOARD_PCA10056
ASMFLAGS += -DBSP_DEFINES_ONLY
ASMFLAGS += -DCONFIG_GPIO_AS_PINRESET
ASMFLAGS += -DFLOAT_ABI_HARD
ASMFLAGS += -DNRF52840_XXAA
ASMFLAGS += -DARM_MATH_CM4

# Linker flags
LDFLAGS += $(OPT)
LDFLAGS += -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -L$(SDK_ROOT)/modules/nrfx/mdk -T$(LINKER_SCRIPT)
LDFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m4
LDFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
# let linker dump unused sections
LDFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections
# use newlib in nano version
LDFLAGS += --specs=nano.specs
LDFLAGS += -Wl,--print-memory-usage

nrf52840_xxaa: CFLAGS += -D__HEAP_SIZE=8192
nrf52840_xxaa: CFLAGS += -D__STACK_SIZE=8192
nrf52840_xxaa: ASMFLAGS += -D__HEAP_SIZE=8192
nrf52840_xxaa: ASMFLAGS += -D__STACK_SIZE=8192

# Add standard libraries at the very end of the linker input, after all objects
# that may need symbols provided by these libraries.
LIB_FILES += -lc -lnosys -lm
```

To debug I'm using GDB with a Jlink server type setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs to explicitly reference the symbol to force it to link, and you need to prevent link optimisation from removing unused references.  Rather then doing a dummy call with potential unwanted side effects, you can simply refer to the symbol via  a function pointer instantiation thus:

```
 void* (*volatile force_malloc_link)(size_t) = &malloc ;
```

Or more simply since you will not actually invoke the function through the pointer:

```
volatile void* force_link_malloc = &malloc ;
```

You could make it generic with a macro for any symbol you wish to link:

```
#define FORCE_LINK( sym ) volatile void* force_link_ ## sym = &sym
```

You can also force the entire library to be linked (if you have the space) - [How to force gcc to link an unused static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116420/how-to-force-gcc-to-link-an-unused-static-library).  One of the answers there explains how you can also unpack the static library and link individual object files.

Comment: Note that if `force_link_malloc` is not actually use, GCC may well optimize it out, so this solution is not better.

Comment: @EmployedRussian - that is what the `volatile` is for.   Moreover it is very seldom you would be running optimised code in GDB in any case.  Not better - I never made any such claim - just an alternative.

Comment: The volatile does not guarantee what you claim it does. And debugging optimized code with GDB is quite common where I come from.

Comment: @EmployedRussian : It does not have to guarantee it - if it does it, it does it.  If empirically it works it does not matter what the standard says _could_ happen - because it didn't happen.  The requirement is to make malloc available in GDB - if malloc is available in GDB _in this instance_; job done - with no side effects.  The possibility of unwanted side effects is a more serious concern I suggest.  When the declaration has global scope the compiler cannot optimise it away (though conceivably the linker could).

Answer (score 0):

> It can't find this function

The function may not be linked into your binary.

- Does your binary *call* `malloc` elsewhere?
- Do you link against `libc.so` or `libc.a`?
- Does `nm a.out | grep ' malloc'` find it?

> it is fine with finding <string.h> fns, like `memcpy`

If your binary calls `memcpy` and you link against `libc.a`, then `memcpy` implementation will be linked in. Using the same `nm` command from above will show that the `memcpy` symbol is present and `malloc` is not.

If you want to call `malloc` at runtime, you need to make sure it's linked in. One way to achieve this is to add:

```
const char *argv0;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  argv0 = strdup(argv[0]);  // This should guarantee that malloc is linked in.
  // rest of the program
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, adding your code snippet seemed to do the job, thanks for that. Actually this also made me realise a rookie error on my end. Malloc is called in my code, but in a function that wasn't actually accessible through normal program flow. The compiler being clever of course decides not to link it in. Whoops!

Comment: Is there a specific reason for invoking `strdup()` to force `malloc()` to link rather than calling `malloc()` directly?  I would suggest perhaps `free( malloc( 0 ) ) ;` having fewer side effects and no memory leak.

Comment: @Clifford No particular reason. You could just use `argv0 = malloc(1);` Using `free(malloc(0))` doesn't work -- GCC knows what `malloc` and `free` do and may optimize this out.

Comment: Fair point re malloc(0).